# cannot create a unary tuple with an empty tuple in it (c++0x)

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I was experimenting with tuples and encountered a problem with creating tuples.
The code example is as follows.

```
//a.cpp
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  auto te = make_tuple();    //this line is ok
  auto tte = make_tuple(te); //this line gives an error.
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with both g++ 4.5 (g++ -std=c++0x a.cpp) and MS VC++2010.
Both compilers are giving me an error on the second line in main().

My question is this:
Since 'te' is a well-defined variable, why can't another tuple be created with te being the content. Is this semantic correct?

I guess this is kind of a boundary case, but if the arithmetic is correct, zero should be allowed, IMHO.

FYI, the error message from gcc is:

```
$ gcc -std=c++0x a.cpp

In file included from a.cpp:1:0:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/tuple: In constructor
  'std::tuple<_Elements>::tuple(std::tuple<_UElements ...>&) [with _UElements = {},
  _Elements = {std::tuple<>}]':

c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/tuple:551:62:   instantiated from
  'std::tuple<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type ...> 
  std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {std::tuple<>&}, typename
  std::__decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type = <type error>]'
a.cpp:6:27:   instantiated from here

c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/tuple:259:70: error: invalid
  static_cast from type 'std::tuple<>' to type 'const std::_Tuple_impl<0u>&'
```

Comment: Smells like a bug to me. :-)  From the messages it seems like the constructor of tuple tries to get access to the copied-from tuple's internals. But tuple<> probably doesn't have any!

Comment: You could try it with libcxx, it certainly is an edge case but it's interesting nonetheless, for interoperability of template code.

Comment: It also seems to compile with gcc 4.6 - time for an upgrade?

Comment: Bo: Thank, I filed a bug at gcc bugzilla and it was confirmed to be a gcc4.5.2. implementation issue. Any idea of a good gcc4.6 binary distribution for mingw? I tried but didn't find one and I am unfortunately tied to windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the compiler has matched your `std::tuple<>` against the following constructor of `std::tuple<std::tuple<>>` (See 20.4.2p15-17 in N3242):

> `template <class... UTypes> tuple(const tuple<UTypes...>& u);`
>
> Requires:
>   `sizeof...(Types) == sizeof...(UTypes)`.
>   `is_constructible<Ti , const Ui &>::value` is true for all `i`.
>
> Effects:
>   Constructs each element of `*this` with
>   the corresponding element of u.
>
> Remark: This constructor shall not
>   participate in overload resolution
>   unless `const Ui &` is implicitly
>   convertible to `Ti` for all `i`.

I think this is a bug in the implementation of `std::tuple` from your compiler; the "remark" implies that this constructor should not be considered, since it won't compile.

Comment: yes, this is confirmed to be gcc 4.5.2 bug and it's related to the copy constructor as I was told and the gcc team have corrected it in 4.6.0. I guess this is what is meant to be on the bleeding edge:)